# Get only duplicate elements from array in swift

Tags: swift

I'm interested in a more elegant way of getting duplicate elements.
I need to find them in order to eventually remove them from the subview.

```
struct People {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let peoples = [
    People(id: 1, name: "Sam"),
    People(id: 2, name: "Tim"),
    People(id: 3, name: "John"),
    People(id: 1, name: "Chris"),
    People(id: 2, name: "David"),
    People(id: 1, name: "Joy")
]

var duplicationPeople: [People] = []
let nondupicatePeople = peoples.reduce(into: [People]()) { one, two in
    if !one.map({$0.id}).contains(two.id) {
        one.append(two)
    } else {
        duplicationPeople.append(two)
    }
}

duplicationPeople.map { print($0) }

// People(id: 1, name: "Chris")
// People(id: 2, name: "David")
// People(id: 1, name: "Joy")
```

Comment: Why is the number 1 listed twice in the output while the number 2 is listed only once?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev The algorithm provided lists duplicates, in order, except for their first occurrence. So I can't make sense of the question. Are we supposed to provide a cleaner way of doing the exact same thing? What would this even be called?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev if you remove two 1 and one 2, then in the end all elements will be unique.

Comment: Oh I see. I was under impression that the code needed to list the elements that occur in the collection more than once. Now that it was edited and there are structs in the collection instead of integers, the title might be even more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you wrote:

```
var seen: [Int] = []
let dupes = peoples.reduce(into: []) { duplicates, person in
    if seen.contains(person.id) {
        duplicates.append(person)
    }
    else {
        seen.append(person.id)
    }
}
```

If you are interested in removing duplicates, you might benefit from `OrderedSet` from https://github.com/apple/swift-collections where you can't have duplicates in the first place, for example:

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

let os = OrderedSet(peoples) // = Sam/Tim/John
```

Comment: I liked the solution above, thx!